# Code igniter not sending select element to database and no error shows up

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im trying to send 3 ids from 3 diferent tables and 1 varchar to a table called 'session', where it will save the ids and this varchar, my problem is, everytime i click to submit, it doesnt input anything to my table, and no error shows up..

**VIEW**

```
<link href='<?php echo site_url('assets/recursos/dashboard.css');?>' rel="stylesheet">
           <div class="container">
           <?php echo form_open('admin/inserirsessao'); ?>
           <?php if (isset($message)) { ?>
           <CENTER><h3 style="color:green;">Data inserted successfully</h3></CENTER><br>
          <?php } ?>

           <div class="col-xs-12">

            <div class="form-group">
           <label for="sel1">Filme</label>

            <select name='filmes' class="form-control" id="filmes">
            <?php
             $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
             $this->db->where('filme_id', $id);
              $lista = $this->db->get('filme');
              foreach($lista->result() as $row) {
              ?>
              <option  value="<?php echo $row->filme_id;?>"> <?php echo $row->Nome; ?></option>
              <?php
                  }
                ?>
             </select>
             </div>

             </div>



             <h2 style="color:white; font-size:25px;">Adiciona um Filme<h2>
             <div class="col-xs-12 ">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="sel1">Seleciona as Salas</label>

              <select name='salas' class="form-control" id="salas">
                       <?php
              $lista = $this->db->get('sala');
              foreach($lista->result() as $row) {
              ?>
              <option  value="<?php echo $row->sala_id;?>" > <?php echo  $row->description; ?></option>
              <?php
                  }
                ?>
            </select>
            </div>

              <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
           <label for="sel1">Seleciona tipo de filme</label>

            <select name="tipofilme" class="form-control" id="tipofilme">
                       <?php
          $lista = $this->db->get('tipo_filme');
          foreach($lista->result() as $row) {
          ?>
              <option  value="<?php echo $row->tipo_filme_id;?>"><?php echo     $row->tipo_filme; ?></option>
              <?php
                  }
                ?>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>

     </div>

     <div class="col-xs-12">






      <p style="color:white" class="text-center">Insere Hora da Sessão</p>    
      <div class="separator">
      <?php echo form_label('Hora:'); ?> <?php echo form_error('hora'); ?>
      <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'hora', 'name' => 'hora')); ?><br />

        </div>


             </div>
          </ul>
          </li>



   <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>   <br/>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?><br/>

  </div>

  </div>

    </div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function index()
{ 



$this->render('admin/inseresessao');



 }

 public function sessao()
 {

 $this->load->library('form_validation');

 $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

  //Validating Name Field

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('hora', 'Hora', 'required');

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  $this->render('admin/inserirsessao');
  } else {
  //Setting values for tabel columns


   $dadossessao = array(
   'hora' =>$this->input->post('hora'),
    'sala_id'=>$this->input->post('salas'),
   'tipo_filme_id'=>$this->input->post('tipofilme'),
   'filme_id'=>$this->input->post('filmes')

    );

    //Transfering data to Model
    $this->insert_model1->form_insert($dadossessao);

    $dadosessao['message'] = 'Dados Foram Inseridos com Sucesso';
   //Loading View
   $this->render('admin/inserirsessao');
   }
   }
   }

    ?>
```

**MODEL**

```
<?php
class insert_model1 extends CI_Model{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}
function form_insert( $dadossessao){

$this->db->insert('session', $dadossessao);
return $dadossessao;

}
} 
 ?>
```

I've been already hours trying to fix the problem but i don't know whats happening, can someone help me?

Comment: Can you try return true instead of return $dadossessao; in your model

Comment: Nothing happen, even tried to post to console see if it shows anything and nothing

Comment: Did your view work fine? Did you try to echo $this->input->post('hora') and all other posts in your controller. Comment all other codes except echo's to check whether you get all your posts. Try this and comment the result

Comment: Getting parse error, can you please me show me how you would do? I'm pretty new to code igniter and i still need some learning for php

Comment: In your controller  function sessao(){ echo $this->input->post('hora') ; } comment if you get error

Comment: @GeordyJames ok i commented the array and did echo on all posts, the view worked but still no sign of errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132520/discussion-between-geordy-james-and-andre-filipe).

Comment: @GeordyJames Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your form action to `<?php echo form_open('inserirsessao/sessao'); ?>` .